# How to do two functions in one IF statement?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to highlight possible mismatch in my data and label them `M1` for 1st mismatch and `M2` for 2nd mismatch for ease of comparison.

It is basically comparing 2 rows of data at a time. `A1=A2`, `B1=B2`, `C1=C3`. But sometimes, `C1<>C3`, then I need to compare other columns in that 2 rows of data so I need a way to highlight that 2 rows.

I want Excel to label both records `M1` and `M2`. I wrote a simple `IF` statement but can't figure out how to label 2 cells.

```
=IF((AND(A1=A2,B1=B2,C1<>C2)),*AND("M1",D2="M2")*,"")
```

Example of output:

[image]

Comment: Can you make your question more clearly, possibly by including sample input data and expected output?

Comment: Hi @KennethL, I've added an example of output expected. Thanks!

Comment: A formula produces a result only in the cell that contains it; one formula cannot produce a result in two different cells.  Each result cell needs to contain its own logic (which can incorporate the result from another cell).

Comment: Are you comparing only consecutive rows?  (i.e. row 6 has to compare with row 5 / row7 only but rows 1 to 4 can be ignored)

Comment: @KennethL, yes, I think comparing consecutive rows is enough

Answer (score 0):

Since your example in the picture is not the same as the description, according to your example I guess you want to do is:

- If A6<>A7 and C6=C7 and D6=D7, then mark cell K6 as "M1" and K7 as "M2".
- Otherwise, leave K6 blank.

What you can do is to cascade `=IF()` and put cell K6 the below formula:

```
=IF(K5="M1","M2",IF(AND(A6<>A7,C6=C7,D6=D7),"M1",""))
```

So the outer `=IF()` checks if the last row is already marked "M1".  If so, it should be "M2".  If not, it will compare columns A,C,D with the next row and see if it needs to be marked "M1".

Comment: Thank you! But if I need to compare rows 1 to 4? Just asking. Your solution has helped solve my problem. But I'm wondering if there's a way to do the other scenario (not just comparing consecutive rows). Thanks!

Comment: You can still use a lot of `IF()` and `AND()` to get it done; otherwise you may need the help of the function `MATCH()`. However it may get too complicated and you may want to revisit your initial purpose and probably re-design the whole table.